# Verify behaviour based on app argument JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

What would be the correct way to verify that one behaviour is triggered when there is an argument being passed, and another behaviour is triggered when there are no arguments being passed when running a java app from cmd?

Since the main method is static it's a little tricky to verify, but I also feel that introducing PowerMock is a bit over the top just for that.

Basically I want to create an object with a constructor with no arguments if there are no cmd arguments, and create an object with a String argument constructor if there are passed arguments to the app.

Comment: What prevents you from calling `main` and passing arguments in your tests?

Comment: See the accepted answer, I decided to rewrite the app as suggested. The problem I guess would be verifying call to object methods as the main method is static meaning you couldn't mock objects that are called from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see your code, so I can only imagine how it looks like.

I can imagine that within the main method some logic is triggered, which results in one or another event.

I suggest thinking about moving the processing of the arguments to another class (`ArgumentProcessor`) which can be fed with a builder object or factory object in the constructor and it could have a `process(String [] args)` method that returns a runnable or whatever you want to achieve.
If you then feed the ArgumentProcessor with a stubbed builder/factory than I think it should be possible to check if the logic has been processed in the right way.